# javascript addEventListener is not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a simple chrome extension that lists all the open tabs, I have this code on it

```
function changeTab(tabID){
  chrome.tabs.update(tabID,{active:false})
}

chrome.windows.getCurrent({populate: true},function (window){
  list = document.getElementById('open-tabs');
  for (var i = 0; i < window.tabs.length; i++)
  {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href','#');
    element.innerHTML = window.tabs[i].title;
    element.addEventListener("click",function(){
      changeTab(window.tabs[i].id);
    },false);
    li.appendChild(element);
    list.appendChild(li);
  }
});
```

It lists the open tabs, but doesn't seem to add the onClick event, when I checked the chrome console I get this

[image: chrome console]

Why is not adding the event correctly?

--edit--
Adding the html if it helps

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Count Me</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <ul id="open-tabs"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Edit2

I tried using the sugestion given on an answer using the `.bind(this,i)` but still doesn't work, I added `console.log()` to see what's happening, and it seems it's not going inside the `addEventListener` heres the code with the log calls:

```
function changeTab(tabID){
  chrome.tabs.update(tabID,{active:false})
}

chrome.windows.getCurrent({populate: true},function (window){
  list = document.getElementById('open-tabs');
  for (var i = 0; i < window.tabs.length; i++)
  {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href','#');
    element.innerHTML = window.tabs[i].title;
    console.log('before');
    console.log(window.tabs[i].id);
    element.addEventListener("click",function(iVal){
      console.log('inside');
      changeTab(window.tabs[iVal].id);
    }.bind(this,i),false);
    console.log('after');
    console.log(window.tabs[i].id);
    li.appendChild(element);
    list.appendChild(li);
  }
});
```

As you can see I have a Before and After `console.log()` as well as inside the `addEventListener` and it doesn't seem to call anything inside the `addEventListener` as you can see here:

[image: chrome console]

It's calling the `console.log` inside the `addEventListener` but still isn't working

[image: chrome console 3]

Comment: It's running on the popup that shows when you click the extension icon, chrome.windows works also document works as it creating the elements inside the list, just the onClick doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean `onClick` does not work... The console events inside the listener will show up when you click the element explicitely. Are you doing that?

Comment: sorry, forgot to add the last screenshot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function callback is happening in a context that does not recognize i..
You can bind the i value to function and by that make it work:

```
element.addEventListener("click",function(iVal){
      changeTab(window.tabs[iVal].id);
    }.bind(this,i),false);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a `closure around` the function

```
(function(num) {
    element.addEventListener("click",function(){
       changeTab(window.tabs[num].id);
    },false);
})(i)
```

The event will be executed a later stage when you click the element. So when the for loop is completed, `i` always points to last iterated value.

So enclosing it in an anonymous function creates a closure around the variable which will be available at the time the click event occurs.

Comment: At the end of the loop `i` actually is window.tabs.length so `window.tabs[i]` points to `undefined` when the event triggers.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen If that is the case then, it should fail before it hits the for loop

Comment: It fails in the event listener because `window.tabs[i]` is undefined so `window.tabs[i].id` will give an error. I'm not sure what you mean by _"it should fail before it hits the for loop"_.

Comment: it's might not be a later stage, you do not control the timing in the async model, it's just a different context where i doesn't exist, furthermore I believe you want to bind to a specific i value and not just the value of i when the function is called, hence better to bind than to use a colsure..

Comment: I meant to say if `window.tabs[i]` is undefined it should fail at this condition itself  `i < window.tabs.length` .. but as that is not failing it is attaching the event listener , but not the right value